# d3 radial wipe animation clips one element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The intent of this code is to click on a pie slice and have all of slices animated in a shrinking and expanding fashion.  When I run the following code for a single element, they all work.  When I try to animate all arcs at the same time, the smallest one disappears. Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fk03xyap/

```
 var data = [50,20,30];
    var svgConfig = {
        height: 1000,
        width: 1000,
        id: 'mySvg',
        transform: 'translate(500,300)'
    };
    var colors = ['blue','gray','green'];

    var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) { return d;});
    var arcGen = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(100)
            .innerRadius(10);
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr(svgConfig);
    var g = svg.selectAll('.arc')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform','translate(100,200)')
            .attr('class','arc');
    var paths = g.append('path').attr('d',arcGen).style('fill',function(d,i){
        return colors[i];
    });

    d3.selectAll('path').on('click', function () {

        var el = d3.select(this);
        var g = d3.select('g');
        var paths = d3.selectAll('path');
        var endAngle,startAngle,orig;
        paths.transition().duration(250).attrTween('d',function(d){
            orig = d;
            console.log('orig',orig);
            endAngle = d.endAngle;
            startAngle = d.startAngle;
            console.log('first');
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.startAngle +.01);
            return function(t){
                d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                return arcGen(d);
            };
        }).transition().duration(755).attrTween('d',function(r){
            console.log('orig new',orig);
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(r.startAngle,endAngle);
            return function(t){
                r.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                return arcGen(r);
            };
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the "original" end angle.  I would stash it in the `d` element for later use.  Cleaning this up, the code simplifies to:

```
d3.selectAll('path').on('click', function () {
    paths.transition().duration(250).attrTween('d',function(d){
        d.origEnd = d.endAngle;       
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.startAngle +.01);
        return function(t){
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return arcGen(d);
        };
    }).transition().duration(755).attrTween('d',function(r){
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(r.startAngle,r.origEnd);
        return function(t){
            r.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return arcGen(r);
        };
    });
});
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fk03xyap/1/).